# Error loading project on git branch change Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Everytime I switch my git branch using intellij, the project does not load properly. Moreover, the project tree structure cannot locate my project folders anymore.

I have my .idea folder with the necessary .iml file.

A temporary fix is to delete the .idea folder and reopen the project in intellij but that takes too much because of indexing.

Comment: Is it a maven project? If so, have you tried auto-import?

Comment: If you checkout the branches into separate working directories, do they all work out of the box when you open IDEA projects?

Comment: Do you have all necessary `.iml`, `.idea` files in `.gitignore`?
In both branches

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ sometimes gets confused all by itself, even without the external changes Korgen described (though that is a good way to consistently reproduce it).

**Click File -> Synchronize, and IntelliJ should see that everything is okay again.**

If that doesn't work, IntelliJ's caches might be corrupt (this used to happen a lot more often than it does now); in that case, regenerate them by

**Clicking File -> Invalidate Caches and restarting the IDE**

(though loading the project will take a while while the caches are recreated).